# Allow duplicate values in 2 dimensional array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Im trying to generate a report of mailbox permissions out of Exchange Online. Here is the code:

```
$SendAs = @()
$Mailboxes = Get-mailbox | where {$_.Identity -notlike "DiscoverySearchMailbox*"}

Foreach ($MB in $Mailboxes) {
    $SendAsTemp = Get-RecipientPermission $MB.userprincipalname | select identity,Trustee,AccessRights | `
        Where-Object {$_.Trustee -notlike "*\Self" -and $_.Trustee -notlike "S-1-5*"}
    if ($SendAsTemp) {
        $SendAs += New-Object psobject -Property @{
            Identity=$SendAsTemp.identity
            Mailbox=$MB.primarysmtpaddress
            Trustee=$SendAsTemp.Trustee
            AccessRights=$SendAsTemp.AccessRights
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the output ($SendAs) is this;

```
Mailbox              Trustee                                 AccessRights           Identity
shared@domain.com    {user1@domain.com, user2@domain.com}    {SendAs, SendAs}       {shared, shared}
```

Its adding the multiple trustee permissions of 'shared' to a single row. What I want is this;

```
Mailbox              Trustee                                 AccessRights           Identity
shared@domain.com    user1@domain.com                        SendAs                 shared
shared@domain.com    user2@domain.com                        SendAs                 shared
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [avoid using the increase assignment operator (`+=`) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/1701026) as it is exponential expensive. Meaning, it gets more expensive with every iteration. Use the PowerShell pipeline instead.

For your specific issue you can simply iterate through the trustees, like:

```
$Mailboxes = Get-mailbox | where {$_.Identity -notlike "DiscoverySearchMailbox*"}

$SendAs = Foreach ($MB in $Mailboxes) {
    $SendAsTemp = Get-RecipientPermission $MB.userprincipalname | select identity,Trustee,AccessRights |
        Where-Object { $_.Trustee -notlike "*\Self" -and $_.Trustee -notlike "S-1-5*" }
    if ($SendAsTemp) {
        Foreach ($Trustee in @($SendAsTemp.Trustee)) {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
                Identity = $SendAsTemp.identity
                Mailbox = $MB.primarysmtpaddress
                Trustee = $Trustee
                AccessRights = $SendAsTemp.AccessRights
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>(Note that in this example whole mailbox entry will not be listed if it doesn't have any trustees at all.)</sub>

Comment: Thanks that works kinda, however now the accessrights and identity have multiple values. For example if there is 2 trustees, then in each row the accessrights field has '{SendAs, SendAs}'. Thanks for info re += performance issues.